# How to programmatically check whether GA4 is installed

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

We are a vendor whose integration sends custom events to our clients' (previously self-installed) GA(s), after dynamically checking for all current installations and IDs.

To dynamically check whether Universal Analytics GA is installed, we use `if ( typeof window.ga == 'function' )` and then `window.ga.getAll().forEach( t =>` to fetch the current `UA-XXX` IDs via `t.get('trackingId')`.

What is the analogous way to dynamically check for GA4 installation and/or fetch the `G-XXX` IDs?

Comment: You might be able to do it by checking the dataLayer for 'config' commands. But I suspect it will not pick up GA4 added by GTM or via Google tag connections in the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tony said, checking DL for config may work for some, but not all cases. You also not always know what the DL name is, it can vary with and without GTM's involvement.

I usually rely on the measurement id in the cookie name or in the actual `collect?` call since both, gtag.js and GTM will add it. You can get access to the `collect?` calls through the performance api. That comes in very handy in Selenium automations. Even gtag implementations through other tag managers will still populate the cookie/call, so it's very robust.

I believe there was a poorly documented gtag api that could be used to look up the measurement ids similarly to how ga used to offer it, but I remember it being less universal than analysing the network requests. Will update this answer if I manage to find it.

Ah, here it is. You can access the measurement ids in the `google_tag_manager` object by iterating through its keys. Despite the name, gtag seems to be putting its context there even when gtm is not loaded.
Yep, seems to be working pretty well:

[image]

Not sure if this is a subject to change with no explicit notification though since the google_tag_manager object is not exactly for public use.

Comment: thanks! so overall `Object.keys( window.google_tag_manager || [] ).filter( e => { return e.substring(0,2) == 'G-' } )` to get all GA4 IDs, or `.length > 0` on that to just get a yes/no re GA4 installation.

i've confirmed this across a couple dozen client sites and it currently works as intended in all cases including GA4-not-installed, and as you mentioned GA4 installed either by the GTM method or the gtag-only method. as you said, noting risk in that this may not be officially supported, but this is the best method for our purposes so far. cookie or collect inspection are options as well.

Comment: yes, all correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to see if the code snippet is there.

```
[...document.body.innerHTML.matchAll(/gtag\('config', '(G-[A-Za-z0-9]+)'\);/gm)][0][1]
```